# Как сделать впадающий пункт в меню Wordpress?

Tags: menu, wordpress

Учусь создавать темы для WordPress. Что-то не могу понять, как сделать выпадающий пункт меню для Wordpress. Например, у меня есть страница "Роботы" и в ней две дочерние "Деревянные роботы" и "Роботы из мороженного". Нужно сделать, что бы при наведении на "Роботы" - вниз выпадали "Деревянные роботы" и "Роботы из мороженного".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В стандартной теме TwentyTen есть то что тебе надо(реализовано на CSS), посмотри и вставь все что нужно себе в тему

Comment: Действительно. Голова уже не соображает. Спасибо :).